# Can I specify instance parameter if I am using forms.Form?

Tags: django

I am currently using `forms.Form` type for one of my forms because I needed to specify many parameters for them, such as queryset, disabled, required.

Snippet of the parameters I am talking about in my `forms.py`

```
class InputClassInformation(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Module.objects.all())
    title = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)
```

The form will allow users to update certain fields in an entry, that means I will have to use the `instance` parameter as seen in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method . However, I get this error when I run my code in `views.py`

```
if Class.objects.filter(module__subject=subject).exists():
   a = Class.objects.filter(module__subject=subject)[0].pk
   form = InputClassInformation(request.POST, instance=a)
```

**Error**:

```
TypeError at /input-class-info/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

I know this would have been fine if I was using `ModelForm`, but trying to specify all the parameters I need in `ModelForm` has been difficult, so is there a way I can specify the instance I want to update while using `forms.Form`?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. A ModelForm is *exactly* the same as a plain Form, except that it takes an instance. So if you could specify your parameters as a Form, you can do it as a ModelForm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added in some of the parameters I specified in my form using forms.Form. I have been having difficulties specifying the same parameters using ModelForm...

Comment: *What* difficulty? You can literally use the same code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The instantiation of fields in the two different forms are different... It would be great if you can show how then

Comment: I don't know what that means. As I say, you can use exactly the same syntax to define those fields in a ModelForm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah, indeed! I've been working on Django for the past month and I've not come across a single example where fields are instantiated the same way. Thank you, I'll proceed to use model forms then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a silly question since I couldn't find the answer, so I'll post an answer just to complete this anyway.

As @DanielRoseman mentioned in the question, we can instantiate the same fields by using the same code in ModelForms. In my case I simply changed my form to:

```
class InputClassInformation(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = '__all__'
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Module.objects.all())
    title = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)
```

and now I can use instance!